# Is there a simple way to give client-side JavaScript access to server-side classes like Enums?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tomcat

Let's say I have classes `Project`, `Employee`, and `ProjectAssignement`.  I have an enum `Role`, with two values, `LEADER` and `FOLLOWER`.  `Employee`s are assigned to `Project`s via the `ProjectAssignment` object, which has a member field `role` of type `Role`.

I have a business rule that each project can only have one leader but can have many followers.  To implement this, I give `Role` a member field `singular`, which is `true` for `LEADER` and `false` for `FOLLOWER`.  (I might add more roles in the future.)  My server-side Java checks if you try to assign multiple leaders to a project and doesn't let you.

So far, I don't think I'm describing anything particularly unusual.

Here is the awkward bit: I have some (handwritten) client-side JavaScript validation to make sure you don't assign multiple people with the same role to a project.  It has a hardcoded exception for followers.  Is there any clean way to just give the JavaScript code awareness of the `Role` enum, so it can access the `isSingular` method?

(Obviously, anything of the sort would actually have to transcribe the `Role` enum into JavaScript at some point; I want to avoid doing that manually or even semi-automatically, because that rapidly becomes more effort than it's worth as I do it for more situations.)

I am not using Spring or any similar framework, just plain .jsps.  Rewriting the whole application to use something like that might be a good idea, but is well beyond the scope of the problem.

Comment: I expanded on Frank's answer below and came up with a quick function to transcribe the whole enum (sans methods).  This code uses reflection, so there are probably a bunch of corner cases and you should use it with caution:

edit: the comment box won't let me paste the code, so here it is on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/5HDhg4e8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually solve this kind of thing by adding a lookup-table in some dynamically-generated Javascript on the page. Maybe the id of the user is the key and their "singularness" is the value. Or maybe you only list those who are less popular (there are likely fewer LEADERs, so only list those). Then just consult the LUT in the javascript.

Actually accessing the ENUMs is not possible. Instead, you'll have to bridge the gap yourself, even if it means basically building a Javascript object that fully-models your server-side object description and then copy all the data.

Comment: :( that's kinda what I figured.

Answer (score 1):

I know you were looking for something built-in, but I got dragged into the semi-automatic conversion after all.

This function will convert any Enum to a JavaScript object:

```
public static <E extends Enum<?>> String getEnumAsJavaScript(Class<E> c)
{
  String name = c.getName().substring(c.getName().lastIndexOf('$')+1);
  String result = "var " + name + " = {";
  for (E o: c.getEnumConstants()) {
    if (o.ordinal() != 0) result += ", ";
    result += " " + o + ": "+ o.ordinal();
  }
  result += " }";
  return result;
}
```

Given an enum and invoation like this:

```
public enum Role { EMPLOYEE, LEADER }

System.out.println(getEnumAsJavaScript(Role.class));
```

It will generate this JavaScript object:

```
var Role = { EMPLOYEE: 0,  LEADER: 1 }
```